# overload stream operator for function

Tags: c++

I am curious if it is possible to overload a `<<` stream operator for a function?

I am using `OutputDebugString` on windows to write to the log, and it only accepts strings.

I am wondering if I can write a function in c++ where I could wrap `OutputDebugString` and do the following

```
MyLogFuntion() << string << int << char;
```

Comment: When this syntax is used the function returns an object and the `operator<<` function is overloaded for that object's type.

Comment: `MyLogFunction()` could return `std::ostream&`. Be careful of the stream object's scope.

Comment: I am confused. How is std::ostream going to write to OutputDebugString

Comment: @ScottF Create your own stream object that redirects to wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can return an object from your function that has `operator <<` and then do the logging in the object's destructor. Then when you call `MyLogFunction()` it will create a temporary object which will store all the data inserted into it and then output it when the object is goes out of scope at the end of the statement.

Here's an [example](http://ideone.com/cBU2dZ) (without The logger function which is actually redundant)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


class Logger {
    std::stringstream ss;
public:
    ~Logger() {
      // You want: OutputDebugString(ss.str()); 
      std::cout<< ss.str(); 
    }

    // General for all types supported by stringstream
    template<typename T>
    Logger& operator<<(const T& arg) {
       ss << arg;
       return *this;
    }

    // You can override for specific types
    Logger& operator<<(bool b) {  
       ss << (b? "Yep" : "Nope");
       return *this;
    }
};


int main() {
    Logger() << "Is the answer " << 42 << "? " << true;
}
```

Output:

> Is the answer 42? Yep

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide overloads in the way you would like to.

If the method you *have* to use (`OutputDebugString` in your case) *forces* you to provide a `std::string` (or similar) parameter, you'll have to provide that parameter somehow.  One way is to use a `std::stringstream`, stream into that, and then pass the result to `OutputDebugString`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << whatever << " you " << want << to << stream;
OutputDebugString(ss.str());
```

You could also dump this into a macro if you really want things more compact:

```
#define OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING(streamdata)   \
  do {                                    \
    std::stringstream ss;                 \
    ss << streamdata;                     \
  } while (0)
```

And then write

```
OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING(whatever << " you " << want << to << stream);
```

Another alternative is to write a more complex wrapper class around `OutputDebugString` which provides stream operators.  But that is probably not going to be worth the effort.